# Proving statement about dimensions of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

While studying for my linear algebra test I came across the following problem:

> Let $f: \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{W}$ be a linear transformation and let
>   $S$ and $T$ subspaces of $\mathbb{V}$ such that $S \cap T =
>  \text{Ker}(f)$. Show that
>
> $$ \dim(S+T) = \dim(\text{Ker}(f)) + \dim(f(S)) + \dim(f(T)). $$

I don't really know how to approach this. There's a good change I have to use that $\dim(S+T) = \dim(S) + \dim(T) - \dim(S \cap T)$, but all I can do with that is transform this into $\dim(f(S)) + \dim(f(T)) = \dim(S) + \dim(T)$. I think the problem here is that I don't know anything about $f(S)$ or $f(T)$. How would one go about proving this?

Comment: Do you mean $S\cap T\subset ker(f)$?

Comment: @Shahab: fixed it.

Comment: The other relation you need is that the dimensions of kernel and image add up to the dimension of the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_T$ be the restriction of $f$ on $T$. Likewise for $f_S$. Using [the rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem):

\begin{align*}
\newcommand{ker}{\operatorname{ker}}
\newcommand{dim}{\operatorname{dim}}
\dim T &= \dim \ker(f_T) + \dim f_T(T) \\
\dim S &= \dim \ker(f_S) + \dim f_S(S)
\end{align*}

It's clear that:
$$
f_T(T) = f(T) \\
f_S(S) = f(S)
$$

Since $\ker(f) = T \cap S$, $\ker(f) \subset T$ and $\ker(f) \subset S$. Therefore:
\begin{align*}
\ker(f_T) = \ker(f) \\
\ker(f_S) = \ker(f)
\end{align*}

Hence:
\begin{align*}
\dim T &= \dim \ker(f) + \dim f(T) \\
\dim S &= \dim \ker(f) + \dim f(S)
\end{align*}

Adding side by side, we get:
$$
\dim T + \dim S = 2 \dim \ker(f) + \dim f(T) + \dim f(S)
$$

By rearranging, we get:
$$
\dim T + \dim S - \dim \ker(f) = \dim \ker(f) + \dim f(T) + \dim f(S)
$$

Since $\ker(f) = T \cap S$, we conclude:
$$
\dim (S + T) =  \dim \ker(f) + \dim f(T) + \dim f(S)
$$

Comment: You mean $\dim S+T$. $S\cup T$ will in general not be a subspace.

Comment: @celtschk You're right. Fixed.